# Passing object ownership in C++

Tags: c++

What is the best way to indicate that an object wants to take ownership of another object? So far, I've been using a `std::auto_ptr` in the public interface, so the client knows that the interface wants to take ownership of the passed object.

However, the latest GCC tells me `auto_ptr` is deprecated, so I wonder what is recommended? `boost::interprocess::unique_pointer` looks like a good candidate, but is this really the best solution out there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`boost::interprocess` is a library for interprocess communication, so I wouldn't use it for different purposes.

As discussed on this forum:

http://objectmix.com/c/113487-std-auto_ptr-deprecated.html

`std::auto_ptr` will be declared deprecated in the next version of the standard, where it will be recommended the usage of `std::unique_ptr`, which requires rvalue references and move semantics to be implemented (that's a fairly complicated feature).

Until the new standard is released, I would simply try to disable the warning if possible, or ignore it, for maximum portability.

If you want to already switch to the next language standard, it is possible since rvalue references have been implemented (see http://russ.yanofsky.org/rref/), so also `std::unique_ptr` should be supported.

On of the advantages of the new semantics is that you can pass to the move constructor also a temporary or any rvalue; in other cases, this allows avoiding to copy (for instance) objects contained inside a `std::vector` (during reallocation) before destroying the original ones.

Comment: 'Will be deprecated' is to strong. The current draft is proposing this change. Wait for it to become a standard.

Comment: yeah. but hands down, it would be very surprising if auto_ptr wouldn't be deprecated. it serves the same purpose as unique_ptr, just in a horrible way :) (abusing the cctor)

Comment: @litb: Though I have come to respect auto_ptr, I agree with you it can be difficult to use correctly. But C++ is way to complex to just assume that unique_ptr is going to be an acceptable replacement without a lot of study and testing, at least auto_ptr's weaknesses are well understood.

Comment: That said. I don't think it is a for gone conclusion that it will be replace. Also Even if it is deprecated auto_ptr will still be with us for a long time (back wards compatibility and all).

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` is indeed the new recommended way.  With C++0x containers will become move-aware, meaning that they can handle types which are movable correctly (i.e., `std::vector<std::auto_ptr<x> >` does not work, but `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<x>>` will).

For `boost`, the `boost::interprocess` containers already support movable types, where `boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` is one of them.  They resemble movable types in pre C++0x by using some of the "normal" boost-template wizardry, and use r-value references where they are supported.

I didn't know about the `auto_ptr` dedicated deprecation, though, but I've not followed the new standard evolution closely.

(**edit**) The implementation of `boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` is indeed not a "public" smart-pointer like `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`, but it is (see [boost.interprocess's site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/unique_ptr.hpp)) not just for shared-memory, but can also be used for general-purpose.

However, I'm quite sure that if GCC deprecates the `auto_ptr` template, they already provide their own `unique_ptr` implementation (not much use to deprecate if you not have a viable alternative yet).

However, that all being said, if you're working on a C++0x platform, use `unique_ptr`, available from the compiler's lib, if not, stick with `auto_ptr`.

Comment: Notice the question asks about boost::interprocess::unique_pointer (actually unique_ptr), which is a smart pointer for shared memory supported by that library.

Comment: Yes, I indeed ignored this more than I should have.  Still, the boost.interprocess's unique_ptr implementation is general purpose, not just for interprocess's shared-memory.  I hope the edit made this more clear, though I doubt it ever more...

Comment: didn't the qustioner ask about why auto_ptr is deprecated. i think this excellent answers it

Answer (score 2):

I agree where possible you should use types where the compiler assists in ownership transfer.

Where you don't have that choice of data types and are passing raw pointers, I follow the Taligent programming guidelines of naming methods which relinquish ownership as **orphanBlah** and parameters which take ownership as **adoptBlah**.

Answer (score 0):

std::auto_ptr implements ownership passing on copy and assignment, so there is nothing special you should do about it:

```
std::auto_ptr< T > p = somePtr; // not p owns object, referenced by somePtr
std::auto_ptr< T > q = myObj.GetAutoPtr(); // not q owns object referenced by auto_ptr in myObj
```

But passing object ownership is not a good design practice, it conducts to leaks and object lifetime relative errors.

Comment: Completely disagree with your conclusion. Ownership passing is well established and a good way of describing what your code does.

Comment: We could agree saying that it can be a messy design practice, to use just when there are good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember std::auto_ptr being deprecated.
Anybody have a link to the appropriate standards meeting where they discuss this?

A quick google found this:
http://objectmix.com/c/113487-std-auto_ptr-deprecated.html

```
>> In fact the latest publicly available draft lists auto_ptr in appendix
>> D, meaning that there is clear intent to formally deprecate it in the
>> next revision of C++. A new class named unique_ptr is going to provide
>> a replacement for auto_ptr, the main difference being that unique_ptr
>> uses rvalue-references instead of voodoo magic to properly achieve
>> move semantic.
>
> Is a reference implementation available? Is it too early to start using it?
>

In order to use unique_ptr you need first to have a compiler which
properly supports rvalue references. These can be hard to find nowadays,
as the feature has not yet been standardized, although the situation is
quickly improving. For example GCC has very recently added the feature
in v4.3 (http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html). If you are lucky
enough to have one of those compilers, most probably they already ship a
version of unique_ptr (it's a sort of benchmark for the feature, you
know). In any case, you can find reference implementations on the
internet by just googling unique_ptr.
```

So it looks like their are moves to deprecate auto_ptr in favor of unique_ptr (which has the same semantics). But it needs a compiler that supports the proposed new features in the upcoming version of C++.

But there is still another meeting and thus vote to come so things could change before the standard is made concrete.