# Boost Smart Pointers and threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, smart-pointers

If you have to pass objects across threads which smart pointer type is best to use?

Assuming the object being passed is thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` would work for sharing data. Its counter is atomic, so you won't run into problems there, and when the last thread is done it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` for shared ownership.

`unique_ptr` to [transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438444/passing-object-ownership-in-c) from thread to thread

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hint: 
There are also really good examples about what you can and what you can't do with shared_ptr in a thread safe manner: [shared_ptr - thread safety](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety) 
Just in case you want to do a bit more that just transfer the ownership